# /usr/bin/find: Argument list too long, getting this while trying to delete 164850 files

Tags: linux, bash, find

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash  
find /mnt/blah/DB/* -mtime +65 | xargs rm -Rf "{}" \;
```

I have also tried the following, but neither works and both get the error as per the title.

```
find /mnt/blah/DB/* -mtime +35 -exec rm {} \;
```

All help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just drop the `*` and do:

```
find /mnt/blah/DB -mtime +35 -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Listing only the top level directory of the directory tree you want to operate on will be sufficient.

Comment: William will this delete the files under the directory or delete the actual directory?

Comment: This will only delete files.  If you want to delete a directory, you must use either `rmdir` or `rm -r`

Comment: in addition to Williams answer, as you have a "-type f" you are only passing files not directories to the exec rm anyway

Comment: My previous comment is not accurate; if you want to delete directories, you can use `-delete` instead of `-exec ...`